# SwiftUI: Failure to Dismiss a View

Tags: ios, swiftui, mobile-development

I have a view which is presented when a network connection fails.
It is called from inside ContentView.NavigationStack:

```
if !networkMonitor.isConnected {
   NetworkTimeout()
}
```

The Warning View itself is:

```
struct NetworkTimeout: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image("netError", bundle: nil)
            Text("The Network is not connected or has timed out")
                .font(.title)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .padding()
            Text("Please check your WiFi or Cell connection, then try again in a few minutes")
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 260)
            Button("Understood", action: {
                dismiss()
                self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

I know the dismiss() and self.presentation...dismiss() are redundant. Viewing them in LLDB shows that are the same. Interestingly, dismiss shows that its value of PresentationMode.isPresented is "false"! despite the view being on screen and the Environment being declared in the current view (As per Apple docs).

Tapping the Understood button executes its action, but the Views stays presented, despite restoration of an active network.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

If `NetworkTimeout` is a sheet/fullscreen then I recommend taking advantage of the `.navigationDestination(isPresented:Binding<Bool>:destination:View)` API. Place this modifier on the "superview".

The `View` in charge of presenting `NetworkTimeout` should have a @Binding boolean flag that will serve as a switch for presenting or dismissing the subview.

So in the method `.navigationDestination` just pass in your `$bindingVariable` and inside the `destination` closure the `NetworkTimeout` instance.

If you are working with `<iOS16` then create a `NavigationLink(isActive:Binding<Bool>:destination:label)` where `isActive` will be the binding flag, `destination` your `NetworkTimeout` and `label` can just be an `EmptyView`. All its left is hiding the link inside a `ZStack`.

Also, NetworkTimeout can the `Binding<Bool>` flag as a stored property and freely change it to `false` to dismiss the view.

p.d: Sorry I couldn't answer the technical part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just because something is on the screen it doesn't mean that it can be "dismissed".

"Presenting" is very specific in `UIKit` it is `show` or `present` in `SwiftUI` it works in conjunction with a `NavigationLink`, `sheet`, `fullScreenCover`, `alert`, etc.

> You can use this action to:
> Dismiss a modal presentation, like a sheet or a popover.

> Pop the current view from a NavigationStack.

> Close a window that you create with WindowGroup or Window.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss

`dismiss` has no way of connecting with `networkMonitor.isConnected` to flip it and remove `NetworkTimeout` from the hierarchy.

`NetworkTimeout` should be removed when whatever tool you are using to monitor network flips `networkMonitor.isConnected` to `true` but that depends on you using one of the property wrappers or macros correctly to tell the `View` when to redraw.